# Juntar 3 imágenes para agregar animaciones con css

Tags: css, imagen

Hola a todos resulta que tengo estas 3 imágenes:

[image: diferentes imagenes]

y necesito juntar las tres imagenes de forma que queden de la siguiente manera:

[image: imagenes juntas]

con que objetivo? poder agregarles animaciones diferentes a cada una con [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), el tema es que necesito que sea responsive, es decir que no se desforme al cambiar de pantalla. Mi pregunta es ¿es posible lograr esto con css? o ¿conocen algúna otra forma la cual me pueda ayudar para lograr lo que necesito?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?¿Te ha dado algún problema las animaciones?¿o hacerlo responsivo?

Comment: me afecta lo responsivo ya que se deforma al cambiar de pantalla

Comment: Deberías compartir el código para ver cómo lo haces ahora mismo, así quizás podamos encontrar la solución que mejor se ajuste a lo que ya tienes

Comment: @HernanHumaña deberias compartir tu codigo, revisa mi respuesta, no entiendo del todo tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo, puse 3 imagenes y usando z-index especifico la profundidad de cada imagen de la siguiente manera:

> primera imagen la pongo que va estar delante `z-index=1`
>
> la segunda imagen estará en medio `z-index=2`
>
> la tercer imagen estara atras `z-index=3`

```css
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#uno{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;

}
#dos{
  z-index:2;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
}
#tres{
  z-index:3;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
}
  img {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
  }
</style>
</head>
```

```html
<img src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Mario-Transparent-Background.png" id="uno">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/water_PNG3290.png" id="dos">
<img src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Yoshi-PNG-File.png" id="tres">
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta. OP está teniendo problemas con la responsividad y no con el posicionamiento. Ya tiene lo que pones o incluso algo más avanzado (porque lo tiene _responsibe_). Sería mejor esperar a que compartiera el código y poder ver qué es lo que realmente falla.